# how to get cache directory from a service: $this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir')

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

So far I was getting the cache directory from some controller. but as I want to set it in a specific service I would like to know which dependancy injection I should do to access it from a service.

Of course I could inject the container (as I settled here below as an exemple) but **I guess there is some more spécific dependancy injection that I could use**.

Here my code so far in my service

```
class mycache
{
   private $container;
   public function __construct($container){
      $this->container = $container;
   }
   public function transf($text, $code)
   {
    $filename = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir') . '/MyCACHE/langue.txt';
   }
}
```

// service configuration

```
service    
cache_langue:
    class: MySite\BlogBundle\Services\mycache
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can inject the `kernel.cache_dir` parameter as follows:

```
services:
    cache_langue:
        class: MySite\BlogBundle\Services\mycache
        arguments: ["%kernel.cache_dir%"]
```